# Critique logo for a lyrics website

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, critique

The logo is for a lyrics website called [Bêjebêje](https://bejebeje.com) (meaning sing sing). The target audience (Kurds) for the logo have a special relationship with the mountains.

[image: logo]

I feel like it works fairly well, but I've shown the logo to two of my friends, and they couldn't see the mountains, they said it looked like a bird's head with a cartoony beak!

What do you think? Do you see mountains and the shape of a B? And if not, any suggestions on how to get it to be instantly recognizable as mountains and the letter B?

Comment: You tainted my mind whit the header name so i can not help but to see mountains because im primed.

Comment: hehe good point, I've removed that from the title.

Comment: Yeah i asked this a bit it seems to be strongly multimodal,

Comment: Maybe you can accentuate the mountain slopes in the leftmost image by extending the white with a line 'above' them -- just a tiny amount. It could be the rounded corners that soften the sharp cutout too much. The negative doesn't work for me I'm afraid. And yes, I do see "mountains".

Comment: Looks like a broken heart, i think maybe it can use a bit more work.

Comment: I didn't see the mountains until I read the word "mountains" in your question. I couldn't work out what it was supposed to represent, my initial thought was that it looked a broken heart. Even with your explanations, I really don't see what it has to do with singing. That aside, it may be a cultural thing in your country to associate mountains with singing, so it might work in certain cultural contexts.

Comment: I didn't see mountains either. Because I was primed for the 'lyrics' part, I saw a weirdly heart-shaped text balloon with the light part on the bottom left the balloon's pointer. My mind could make nothing of the rightmost mountain.

Comment: @Vincent maybe the mountains have some perspective error since they both look same size? Anyway i have a hard time seeing a B... The heart shape overrides my mind here. Anyway all of this might not be a bad thing, if it solves your problem. But if you aimed to show B and mountains your in trouble.

Comment: I couldn't see any mountains as well. Before reading the question took me a while to figure out what was the shape: heart, balloon, stylised B with something abstract at the bottom. No music, no mountains for me.

Comment: I'm sorry but I just see sideways heart break. Even after seeing the mountains my mind returns to a heart. However, I had to try really hard to see the bird. Not sure if it's a cultural thing or not but I am from the U.S.

Comment: I see the side profile of a pregnant woman.

Comment: I see JPG compression where there shouldn't be any... (Sorry, couldn't resist.)

Comment: I saw a breaking heart, then a few seconds later I saw the mountains. I didn't notice a "B" shape until I read the name of the website, but that is clear to me also. I really believe this is a pretty brilliant design.

Comment: Unprimed art-student daughter said "A crumbling heart" then, when asked for more, "A bird pecking at a heart". OTOH, if people know the name of the service, they may be primed to see the B.

Comment: I see Homer Simpson's head, unfortunately, and now I can't unsee it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reality is that it honestly **doesn't matter** what anyone sees in the shapes. There's no rule or "law" stating logos must be literal as they relate to the company when viewed. Ambiguity is **not** always a bad thing. If it is a strong, striking, mark, it's good. I mean, the Amazon smile looks like borderline profanity to me...

*Eventually* people will see mountains.

I'd merely question the small, almost "lightning bolt looking" shape at the bottom left.

I think it merely needs slightly more attention to the mountain aspect... making the mountains larger, or the B less overwhelming, should detract from the "heart" appearance to a degree. I'd play around with that. It's still going to look like a heart to many, but so what.

[image]

Note that once you see the mountains.... the tendency is to always see them. Kind of like the FedEx arrow... once you see it, you always see it. In my book, that sort of ambiguity is a very **good thing**.

Related: [Designers response in an adverse situation during the presentation of a project](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/110017/designers-response-in-an-adverse-situation-during-the-presentation-of-a-project)

Comment: .. in support of my theory regarding the Amazon smile, I encourage you to Google Image search for the rocket, Blue Origin, that Jeff Bezos wants to launch into space.

Comment: Would removing the rounding from the first section of the B (at the top of it) and straightening the back of it make it more clear as a B, or is that frowned upon?

Answer (score 14):

I also saw a heart, breaking up at the bottom.

I would suggest not breaking the B, and containing the mountains within it.

A quick and dirty redraw below. I's advise also to keep working on the mountains, they're not all that obvious.

People will probably keep seeing a heart also, but that's not really a problem, since that's a positive symbol of 'liking' or 'loving' something.

[image]

Comment: It's supposed to be a "B"?!?! Oof, I was way off. I agree with your rendition.

Comment: I agree that keeping the border makes it read like a "B". (That's a B? I really had no idea.) But also consider that mountains within border = more contained, less powerful; mountains breaking border = more powerful and dynamic.

Answer (score 6):

I didn't see a mountain at all. The main problem is that you can't see the difference between the two peaks. Try something like having a background-color line cut the behind front mountain to add to the perspective.  [image: Example logo]

Comment: That actually helps making it look less like a broken heart.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, the jury is out in the comments. Seems to me that the image is very multimodal. As in it can be seen in many ways. I think the heart is such a strong symbol that everybody recognizes it. This might override the B for many people to see a heart (I didn't see the B initially), also a broken heart is a common symbol so again that overrides a lot. I can also see a bird, hunched over man with a lightning beard, etc.. And the mountain.

But here is the thing none of this is bad as such. Having a broken heart for mountains in shape of a B, that evokes a bird and zeus. If that's your intention. Its also not necessary for people to know what the logo is. I mean take the Citroën's logo (below). Did you know it is actually supposed to represent a [herringbone gear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herringbone_gear). Not knowing this does not detract form the logo, in any way.

[image]

**Image 1**: Citroën's Logo, what does it depict?

So I mean it is not necessarily a bad logo. But it might need some work... As I feel it may be a bit too busy for a logo.

Answer (score -1):

Try making it all an outline, I think that would help making the B look more like B not a heart.

Answer (score -2):

I would say keep the original design, and add the name (in an appropriate font) along with. I think having that would tie things together.