# Should a small business change their logo after 15 years in business?

Tags: logo, branding, business, perspective, marketing

I am currently in the process of handing over my business that is a Waxing spa located in Portland, Oregon to my 18 year old daughter.

However, she has decided that our logo needs to change, for the fact it may be offensive to non binary clients and feels that is the reason for declining numbers of clients booking (I stated the obvious, people left Portland, Oregon in droves hence Covid) as well I have semi retired so my availability is very limited I have been the face of the business for the past 12 plus years.

Her reasoning for this change is we have a Mars/Venus planetary symbol in our logo. Meaning it screams male or female in many peoples eyes. I explained to her, we are either waxing a male part or a female part on the body for intimate waxing. We do have gender fluid named waxes like "The Lavern Cox" or "The Chaz Bono."  I have also advertised as a non-binary spa all along. What ever a person may think they are in their mind has nothing to do with the physical body part you we are waxing in my opinion.

I was taught in my business course and by also owning a successful business that you should never bastardize your logo in any way, shape, or form. Especially when people recognize it as your trademark. I call it Marketing 101.

Since we are located in Portland, Oregon she feels we need to be more gender fluid! I would love some feedback on this subject. I personally feel this will be a HUGE MISTAKE!

[image: shop name next to interlinked male and female symbols (♂/♀)]

Comment: Hey Regina. This is a bit too opinion based for a Q&A site like this one

Comment: This is not an answer but some comments.

>Should a small business change its logo after 15 years in business?

Almost every company changes its logo from time to time. But most of the time is for stylistic reasons.

Comment: Do not base your decisions on hunchs, either one way or the other.

>I call it Marketing 101. 

What would be really a marketing strategy is to conduct a marketing survey. But do not make one "is it offensive?" Everything can be at one point or another. Hire some designers to make proposals that reflect the service.

Comment: Make questions like "Do you recognize this business?" Do you understand what the business is for? Etc. Hire a marketing person to make a good survey for you.

Comment: >Especially when people recognize it as your trademark
**Ask your current customers. Those are the priority**. You probably should never expand at the cost of your current clients. But for external people, I don't think that could qualify as a "trademark" Is it a "matching couples business" or "Wedding service?"

Comment: Try to think in the long term. What would be a good image if I expand a franchise to another country? for example. You can probably modernize your brand with an excellent typography-only logo. Currently, the typography is too generic.

Comment: I agree this question is too opinion based, but FWIW, I think the logo looks outdated regardless of the issue you mentioned. I would ask if you really even need the interlinked gender symbols. To be honest, it's not exactly a unique or memorable design/trademark.  Also, you probably wouldn't be able to register that as a trademark anyway, since it is a commonly used symbol. Many really big and well known global companies have drastically changed their logos/branding over the years.  This is certainly not unheard of. If I were you, I'd hire a a graphic designer to come up with some ideas.

Answer (score 18):

This question is entirely opinion-based and much of what follows is indeed **merely my *opinion*** based upon experience. However, it if were *my* business and *my* logo in 2023, I'd be diligently working on an update or refresher for the logo.

---

> *"What ever a person may think they are in their mind has nothing to do with the physical body part"*

This appears to be a generational thing based upon the above statement.

Forgive me, but I'd guess you're most likely a "GenX"er - possibly a "Boomer" or "Cusper".  Expressing such a thought appears to be common in past generations. It is *not* my intention to express agreement nor condemnation for *that* mindset. In fact, my point in this answer is that *your* mindset is essentially **irrelevant** in terms of marketing.

I can see that there was perhaps a conscious *effort* when the original logo was created to convey that "Men are welcome!" Otherwise, why use such overly common, perhaps trite, gender symbology for a logo - there'd be no need. I imagine the "goal" at the time of creation was *specifically* to appear non-gender specific so as to *not* alienate anyone based upon their gender.

Seems to me, your daughter may be merely asking for that *same consideration* a decade and a half later - to appear non-gender specific. It's merely that times have changed and "gender" has been somewhat redefined in today's "social dictionary."

Today... "gender" is *not* the same as biology or physiology in the *social* dictionary. *This* is where there has been a generational shift.

- Older generations associate "gender" directly with ***physiology*** 
  - the "parts" one has are **defining**.
- Younger generations associate "gender" directly with ***identity*** 
  - the "parts" one has are **irrelevant**.

There's a marked difference in the thinking. This shift is what I believe you may be conceptually overlooking.

---

Effective marketing is about what will **attract**, and *not* repel, the desired target audience.

So, naturally, the first question to ask oneself is "Who would need my services/products?"

Perhaps I'm incorrect, but I'd wager most people seeking waxing services are between the ages of 18-49. And I'd *guess* clientele tends to be more on the younger side of that age range. You should consider yourself lucky you have a direct connection with that generation via your daughter. Rest assured, if *she* has brought this up **she's not alone in her thinking** for her age group.

One may disagree with younger generations. However, that does not mean they are incorrect. Their perception is their perception. A business/company either uses marketing to "play" to that mindset or dismisses the mindset, the age group, and possibly their dollars. (Which may be appropriate for some businesses.)

The logo centers on *physiological traits*. While not incorrect - due to shifting mindsets of the times, **using less human physiological imagery may be wise**. Referencing binary biological genders can be hazardous in today's social climate. People - politicians, celebrities, *doctors*, professors - have all been "cancelled" for merely stating that they believe gender is binary. Your business **is** stating the exact same thing via the logo imagery.

**The age range you may be targeting has shown a propensity to be offended by such biological references.** So, it's your choice, you either acquiesce to that younger way of thinking or you choose to ignore it and possibly forego gaining clients from that age group.

**Your call. But the choice is really that cut and dry.**

---

Logos absolutely change the longer they are in use. Social perceptions change. It's not about what you believe, it's **what your clients believe.**

Updating a logo is *not* the same as bastardizing a logo. While you are correct that logos should *never* be bastardized for individual use cases, "updating" a logo is a common thing. Many big brands update their logo about once a decade - give or take a few years.

- https://logos-world.net/att-logo/
- https://designbro.com/blog/brand-logos/burger-king-logo/

Logos are updated to remain viable in current social trends. The goal in updating a logo should be to retain recognition as much as possible while avoiding any appearance of being "dated" or "out-of-touch" and certainly avoid "offending" social mindsets. As times change, logos often need a "refresher" in order to retain the same "pull" they once had.

Updating a logo is not a "never" thing. In fact, it is often **a *necessary* thing** the longer the business is in operation.

---

I'd also point out that *any* possible pitfall in changing logo imagery after a decade is really only a matter to consider when there's been a *considerable* amount of exposure for the existing imagery. The breadth and scope of the logo usage is a factor. As is the uniqueness (which the symbology used here is not). For smaller local businesses this is often a non-issue, *especially* service-based businesses which have no hard products to rebrand.

Existing local clientele knows the business by *name* and that is more important than the imagery associated with that name. Word-of-mouth centers on the *name* not the logo imagery. If the business is not a national, international, or a franchise business and all the clients are local - it's really not an issue to update or change a logo after a decade.

In fact, a logo refresher *may* be enticing to past clients -- they see a new logo, but know the name. It's conveyed that things have changed, they may be enticed to revisit your services to see what else has changed.

In a *local market*, the current logo imagery is either **inconsequential** to older viewers or ***possibly* offensive** to younger viewers.

As a business owner, why would one ***not*** seek to remove the sheer *possibility* of making an offensive first impression via logo imagery? Or appear to be retaining "old world" thinking? If the logo conveys you still *think* in 2010 terms then why would anyone who is offended by that generational thinking look deeper to see any "service names"?? If you offend via the logo, prospective clients will **never** see your service names which may convey a more modern mindset. You only get *one chance* at making that first impression - the logo.

For a local market, the *only* thing changing this logo could do is ***improve*** client acquisition. There's no marketing downside to a logo change as I see it.

---

Social climates are simply not the same in 2023 as they were 2000 or even 2010. The last decade has seen remarkable shifts in the mindsets of the general public. As younger generations reach the "spending" age, one needs to consider their perceptions to keep marketing effective. *Especially*, if they are a core demographic you are targeting.

All this has **nothing** to do with whether you agree or disagree with any generational or "social group" thinking. It is *entirely* about *effective* marketing and **how to pull in clientele.** Your beliefs or opinions regarding *any subject* are entirely irrelevant if they contradict what your target audience has ***proven*** to believe.

---

#### TL;DR:

It is the **target audience** a logo should appeal to, **not** the business owner/operator. If a logo consists of imagery the target audience has *proven* to be offended by, the logo should change.

The *specific* symbology in the current logo is used to denote *heterosexuality*. [A wide range of more inclusive symbols exists](https://www.istockphoto.com/vector/gender-line-icons-sex-identity-emblems-sexual-orientation-sign-lgbt-symbols-of-gm1283888333-381188535). In today's society, the logo imagery essentially states, in bold, broad terms... **this business is a *heterosexual* business**. That clear, defined, message is *not* desirable for any business which strives to be inclusive.

To put things in short, clear, terms.... There are other, much larger, national and international brands which have changed their logos recently due to new evolving in social views that now *recognize* them as being offensive. Key phrase here is "now recognize" - these brand logos have *always* been offensive to certain social groups but just recently have been acknowledged as being offensive by the brands themselves. A logo change due to new or evolving social views is not uncommon.

- https://america.cgtn.com/2020/06/22/see-whos-changing-their-offensive-logos-and-whos-not

---

<sub>**Sidebar:** I'd also point out for the existing logo - in the past, including circa ~2005 when it may have been created, the *interlocking* of the two gender symbols was often used to convey *heterosexual intercourse* - all through the 70s, 80s, 90s, etc. that's what the interlocking **often** meant - otherwise the symbols would **not** interlock. It *may* have been an inappropriate logo from its inception and no one noticed or said anything. In fairness, marketing associated with weddings was also another common reason the symbols would interlock - but there was still the connotation of sex between a man and a woman. This matter somewhat refers to [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/110017/designers-response-in-an-adverse-situation-during-the-presentation-of-a-project) regarding perceptions.</sub>

---

Comment: yeah i think many business owners forget that the logo is not really for them as such

Comment: This may be far-fetched, but I'll point out that some business have generated substantial publicity by deliberately faking being "cancelled". This could go either way: either have someone criticize the logo, change the logo immediately and attract millennials, or have someone criticize the logo, stubbornly refuse to change it and attract boomers.

Comment: Are "boomers" a big part of waxing clientele??  "Hey grandma.. come on we're late for your waxing!!" hmmm.. I'd guess not `:)` I personally think it's not a great logo initially due to the heterosexual symbology. Regardless of generational shifts. The logo, to me, says "Sex" not "Wax". --- maybe they sell surfboards and Sexwax is viable `:)`

Comment: The sidebar is important. Having grown up in the 70s, the symbolism is actually what we would have called skeevy. I don't find it particularly offensive but trite.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, change this logo.

- A good branding update never hurt anyone, especially after 15 years of business. Some people will be of the opinion that a branding update is risky, and you can see that in the comments below, there's always somebody that heard some big brand story. Ignore the stories and take arguments.
- In your particular case, it is my opinion this logo looks dated. Whatever logo somebody does for you in 2023, it will look better than this logo. Whatever some people will say, a new logo does not need to cost you much. You can literally buy a decent quality, ready made logo for 30$ if a low cost is critical.
- In 2023, you need to be careful about gender issues. You may find arguments for this and that, but in reality better avoid directional gender statements. If this is a skin care business, there are many other ways to design a new logo for a spa.
- Be open minded. Literally putting a rainbow in a new logo has the potential to improve your business :) I am not saying you should do this specifically, just saying try to flip your perspective and accept the new.

Comment: Mindlessly putting a rainbow in your logo, without more than lip-service support for the causes it stands for, is also the shortest route to being loathed as 'performative' by the open minded audience you're trying to reach in the first place.

Comment: "A branding update never hurt anybody" - very definitely not true. "Literally putting a rainbow in a new logo has the potential to improve your business" - also reasonably likely to annoy people.

Comment: There we go, as subjective as it gets :) This logo is 100% screaming 90's clipart, and 100% needs a refresh. In some places, they use these symbols for toilets, so I can't even call it a logo, its a mix of commonly used symbols and poor typography. For the rainbow, you can take that lightly, I said "has the potential", the rest is for the owner to evaluate.

Comment: A branding update after 15+ years of business has certainly hurt multiple companies (e.g. GAP 2010, Kraft 2009, Tropicana 2009, Mastercard 2015, Leeds United 2018 are some clear disasters) and even if it doesn't hurt, rebranding just for the sake it can easily be a huge waste of money. A brand logo *may* need updating after some time because audience views have changed - and this logo might well be one of these cases - but it's definitely not universal, and just being 15 years in business (which, frankly, isn't that much) without change by itself is not a sufficient reason for rebranding.

Comment: One can't compare the brand of a *local* walk-in business against multi-million dollar international brands (Kraft, Tropicana, et al.). They are not similar.

Comment: Guys, this is my answer to the owner. Write your own answers. This is a toilet logo, he needs to change it now. Rainbows or not, whatever. He can get a 30$ logo from from graphic river, and it will look better. What huge waste of money.. this is a street corner business, not Coca Cola.

Comment: Lucian, my comment was directed at Peteris, not you. `:)`

Comment: I know Scott, I was responding to all the other guys, encouraging this person to keep the toilet logo. You know how designers always get shocked and paralized when a big brand changes logo. Oh no, its the end of the world, then Adobe buys Figma, and all those disaster designer stories. Brothers, brands and their marketing need to change. Their owners change, their investors change. It also happens with this guy, his daughter is taking over. There's literally a new owner.